# How to override WindowDidLoad with other changes

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am having a class that overrides ReactiveWindowController.

I need to get the reference of Observer that in the base class. But as it is not there. I decided to override it.

```
/// <inheritdoc/>
    public override void WindowDidLoad()
    {
        base.WindowDidLoad();

        // subscribe to listen to window closing
        // notification to support (de)activation
        NSNotificationCenter
            .DefaultCenter
            .AddObserver(NSWindow.WillCloseNotification, _ => _deactivated.OnNext(Unit.Default), Window);

        _activated.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    }
```

How can I override and change the `NSNotificationCenter....` codes with mine. So that I can unregister it as per my requirement.

If there are any other ways to do it please let me know.

PS: I am new to Xamarin.

Comment: You should just take the source and mod' it : https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/4a7b6c7cb35efe4e936b6779e2ad60964894e1d0/src/ReactiveUI/Platforms/mac/ReactiveWindowController.cs

Comment: @SushiHangover: I tried that, used the same namespace. For all the Getxxxx I get errors as "MyReactWC does not have the definition for Getxxx". How to get rid of it? What reference or assembly I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve this if your class is derived from ReactiveWindowController. This is not a correct implementation by React.

You could create your own version of ReactiveWindowController. Copy the source and change the class name.

Comment: I tried that, used the same namespace. For all the Getxxxx I get errors as "MyReactWC does not have definition for Getxxx". How to get rid of it? What reference or assembly I need to use?